# Obexpushd Can't Initialize Via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm relatively new to the Raspberry Pi and am trying to receive data via Bluetooth on my Raspberry Pi. I've opted to use obexpushd and have installed all the bluetooth packages needed. However, when I run the command

```
obexpushd -B -n
```

to initialize obexpushd and have it listen to any incoming Bluetooth messages, it gives me this error message:

```
Listening on bluetooth/[00:00:00:00:00:00]:9   
SDP session setup failed, disabling bluetooth  
net_init() failed
```

I'm pretty sure that I've paired and connected the Raspberry Pi and device correctly so I'm at a loss for why it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

You have an issues with your bluetooth sdp. Try stopping it

```
$ sudo service bluetooth stop
```

And restart it

```
$ sudo bluetoothd --compat
```

I had the same issue and it worked for me.

Comment: I also have same problem , i am getting Failed to connect to SDP server on 11:22:33:44:55:66: Host is down  as i tried above method.

Answer (score 0):

Subert's Answer Worked for me, I was wondering that hci was not discoverable.
In addition of Subert's Answer:

```
service bluetooth stop
bluetoothd --compat &
obexpushd -B -n &
```

For me the hciconfig was down, so i started it as:

```
hciconfig hci0 up
```

Now every thing is fine,
Thanks for subert's Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Though @Subert is correct, a better way to run the daemon in compat mode is to extend the systemd script. This solution allows you to use the start/stop scripts and will survive any updates.

Create the file */etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service.d/compat.conf* with the following:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd —compat
```

I decided to name the file *compat.conf* but you can name it whatever you want.

Reload & restart the daemon, and you're done!

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo service bluetooth restart
```

I didn't have to run the `hciconfig` command but do have to run `obexpushd` as root (using sudo) until I figure out a better way.